# Redis performance on a multi core CPU

Tags: redis, cpu, cpu-usage, jedis

I am looking around redis to provide me an intermediate cache storage with a lot of computation around set operations like intersection and union.

I have looked at the redis website, and found that the redis is not designed for a multi-core CPU. My question is, Why is it so ?

Also, if yes, how can we make 100% utilization of CPU resources with redis on a multi core CPU's.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **I have looked at the redis website, and found that the redis is not designed for a multi-core CPU. My question is, Why is it so?**

It is a design decision.

> *Redis is single-threaded with epoll/kqueue and scales indefinitely in terms of I/O concurrency.* --@antirez (creator of Redis)

A reason for choosing an event-driven approach is that *synchronization* between threads comes at a cost in both the software (code complexity) and the hardware level (context switching). Add to this that the bottleneck of Redis is usually the network or the *memory, not the CPU. On the other hand, a single-threaded architecture has its own benefits (for example the guarantee of atomicity).

Therefore event loops seem like a good design for an [*efficient* & *scalable*](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) system like Redis.

> **Also, if yes, how can we make 100% utilization of CPU resources with
> redis on a multi core CPU's.**

The Redis approach to scale over multiple cores is *[sharding](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning)*, mostly together with [Twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy).

However if for some reason you still want to use a multi-threaded approach, take a look at [Thredis](https://github.com/grisha/thredis) but make sure you understand the implications of what its author did (you can not use it as a replication master, for instance).

Comment: That is really interesting. I am looking at using redis without persistence, and with heavy CPU intensive set operations as compared to more as a cache. Would there be any downsides of using thredis for the same, considering the design implications.

Comment: Just want to add another couple reasons redis being single core makes sense: 1: For many redis work loads the system memory bandwidth will likely cause a bottleneck before the CPU. It is a super efficient data structure server. 2: The evented single-thread architecture makes it much easier for redis to guarantee all operations are atomic.

Comment: At this moment, twemproxy's last commit belongs to 2 years ago. Is it still reliable?

Answer (score 2):

Redis server is a single threaded. But it allows to achieve 100% utilization of CPU resources using Redis nodes (master and/or slave).

1. Read operations could be scaled using Redis master/slave configuration with single master. One of CPU core used for master node and all others for slaves.
2. Write operations could be scaled using Redis multi-master cluster configuration. Multiple CPU cores used for master nodes and all others for slaves.

[Redisson](https://redisson.org) - Redis Java client which provides full support of Redis cluster. Works with AWS Elasticache and Azure Redis Cache. It includes master/slave discovery and topology update.